# How to install (get) LINQ in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can I install LINQ in my Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is already installed. Create a project targeting .NET 3.5 referencing the `System.Core` assembly and you should be ready to go. If you want to use Linq to SQL or Linq to XML you might need to reference additional assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to

```
using System.Linq;
```

[System.Linq Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx)